# Split data to make train and test sets - for loop - insert variable to subset by row

Tags: r

I am trying to subset this data frame by pre determined row numbers.

```
       # Make dummy data frame
 df <- data.frame(data=1:200)
        train.length <- 1:2

# Set pre determined row numbers for subsetting
train.length.1 = 1:50
test.length.1 = 50:100
train.length.2 = 50:100
test.length.2 = 100:150

train.list <- list()
test.list <- list()
# Loop for subsetting by row, using row numbers in variables above
for (i in 1:length(train.length)) {
  # subset by row number, each row number in variables train.length.1,2etc..
  train.list[[i]] <- df[train.length.[i],]  # need to place the variable train.length.n here...
  test.list[[i]] <- df[test.length.[i],] # place test.length.n variable here..
  # save outcome to lists
}
```

My question is, if I have my row numbers stored in a variable, how I do place each [ith] one inside the subsetting code?

I have tried:

```
df[train.length.[i],]
```

also

```
df[paste0"train.length.",[i],]
```

however that pastes as a character and it doesnt read my train.length.n variable... as below

```
> train.list[[i]] <- df[c(paste0("train.length.",train.length[i])),]
> train.list
[[1]]
   data data1
NA   NA    NA
```

If i have the variable in there by itself, it works as intended. Just need it to work in a for loop

Desired output - print those below

```
train.set.output.1 <- df[train.length.1,]
test.set.output.1 <- df[test.length.1,]
train.set.output.2 <- df[train.length.2,]
test.set.output.2 <- df[test.length.2,]
```

I can do this manually, but its cumersome for lots of train / test sets... hence for loop

Comment: `?caret::createTimeSlices`

Comment: Good example here http://topepo.github.io/caret/data-splitting.html

Comment: Will it subset the entire data frame?

Comment: I need to split my entire data frame into train and test periods. No sure if caret can do that, first glace, no

Comment: To split, just set the `initialWindow` and `horizon` parameters to numbers that will add to the number of observations of `y`, e.g. `caret::createTimeSlices(1:10, 8, 2)`. If the sum is smaller, it will generate folds for cross validation.

Comment: My question is, i need to subset all rows in data frame

Comment: Right; pass in your outcome column, and it will return a list of row indices, e.g. `caret::createTimeSlices(mtcars$mpg, 25, 7)`. Subset with those to make training and test sets.

Comment: I need ALL columns in data frame

Comment: Thus the subsetting; it returns indices, not data frames. You could equally well pass in `seq(nrow(mtcars))`, as it's only used to determine length.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider staggered `seq()` and pass the number sequences in `lapply` to slice by rows. Also, for equal-length dataframes, you likely intended starts at 1, 51, 101, ...

```
train_num_set <- seq(1, 200, by=50)
train.list <- lapply(train_num_set, function(i) df[c(i:(i+49)),])

test_num_set <- seq(51, 200, by=50)
test.list <- lapply(test_num_set, function(i) df[c(i:(i+49)),])
```

Comment: This satisfies the example, in real life, i need train sets to be 252 rows long, with test sets 126. There is no way I make the method work that im trying in my example? Use a variable within the subset to do it per the loop?

Answer (score 1):

**Create a function that splits your data frame into different chunks:**

```
split_frame_by_chunks <- function(data_frame, chunk_size) {
    n <- nrow(data_frame)
    r  <- rep(1:ceiling(n/chunk_size),each=chunk_size)[1:n]
    sub_frames <- split(data_frame,r)
    return(sub_frames)
}
```

**Call your function using your data frame and chunk size. In your case, you are splitting your data frame into chunks of 50:**

```
chunked_frames <- split_frame_by_chunks(data_frame, 50)
```

**Decide number of train/test splits to create in the loop**

```
num_splits <- 2
```

**Create the appropriate train and test sets inside your loop. In this case, I am creating the 2 you showed in your question. (i.e. the first loop creates a train and test set with rows 1-50 and 50-100 respectively):**

```
for(i in 1:num_splits) {
   this_train <- chunked_frames[i]
   this_test <- chunked_frames[i+1]
}
```

Just do whatever you need to the dynamically created train and test frames inside your loop.